# How to Create a Spider Plot in Gnuplot?

Tags: graph, plot, gnuplot

I would like to produce a spider (aka radar/star) plot using Gnuplot where different axes have independent scales. I am able to produce such a plot using OriginPro (commercial), but with Gnuplot I am only able to set a radar plot with uniform scale.

The (csv file) dataset looks like the following (first row is column labels):

```
# FEATURE, Product_A, Product_B, Product_C, Product_D
attribute_1, 2, 10, 7, 3.5
attribute_2, 1, 0.5, 3,4
attribute_3, 37, 58, 49, 72
attribute_4, 1985, 1992, 2006, 2010
attribute_5, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.8
```

and the plot I am looking for is this one: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uvqubzqvm6puhb8/spider.pdf -
As you can see each axis stands for a different attribute, and has its own scale.

I guess the Gnuplot starting code is:

```
set polar
set grid polar
set angles degrees
set size square
set style data filledcurves
```

But I don't know how to proceed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @george helped me figure out how to rearrange the dataset, in order to pick from it the corresponding attribute data.
Because I was also looking for different range scales for the different spider axes, in addition to @george's suggestion, I thought that an axis-specific normalisation to the common [0:1] range, would have the problem solved. The main modification is then related to the `using` field of the `plot` command.

The code is fairly lengthy, I'm sure it could be optimised. It could also be merged into a script or a simple C code, in order to let the user decide the number of axes (number of attributes), and the different ranges (min, max) for each specific axis.

The following example is for 5 attributes comparing 2 products. Here is shown the [plot result image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7fqzelbfu0ldvfd/gnu-spider.pdf):

```
set nokey
set polar
set angles degrees
npoints = 5
a1 = 360/npoints*1
a2= 360/npoints*2
a3= 360/npoints*3
a4= 360/npoints*4
a5= 360/npoints*5
set grid polar 360.
set size square
set style data lines
unset border
set arrow nohead from 0,0 to first 1*cos(a1) , 1*sin(a1)
set arrow nohead from 0,0 to first 1*cos(a2) , 1*sin(a2)
set arrow nohead from 0,0 to first 1*cos(a3) , 1*sin(a3)
set arrow nohead from 0,0 to first 1*cos(a4) , 1*sin(a4)
set arrow nohead from 0,0 to first 1*cos(a5) , 1*sin(a5)
a1_max = 10
a2_max = 5
a3_max = 100
a4_max = 2020
a5_max = 1
a1_min = 0
a2_min = 0
a3_min = 50
a4_min = 1980
a5_min = 0
set label "(0:10)" at cos(a1),sin(a1) center offset char 1,1
set label "(0:5)" at cos(a2),sin(a2) center offset char -1,1
set label "(50:100)" at cos(a3),sin(a3) center offset char -1,-1
set label "(1980:2020)" at cos(a4),sin(a4) center offset char 0,-1
set label "(0:1)" at cos(a5),sin(a5) center offset char 3,0
set xrange [-1:1]
set yrange [-1:1]
unset xtics
unset ytics
set rrange [0:1]
set rtics (""0,""0.25,""0.5,""0.75,""1)

plot '-' using ($1==1?a1:($1==2?a2:($1==3?a3:($1==4?a4:($1==5?a5:$1))))):($1==1?(($2-a1_min)/(a1_max-a1_min)):($1==2?(($2-a2_min)/(a2_max-a2_min)):($1==3?(($2-a3_min)/(a3_max-a3_min)):($1==4?(($2-a4_min)/(a4_max-a4_min)):($1==5?(($2-a5_min)/(a5_max-a5_min)):$1))))) w l
1 8
2 3
3 67
4 2000
5 0.2
1 8

plot '-' using ($1==1?a1:($1==2?a2:($1==3?a3:($1==4?a4:($1==5?a5:$1))))):($1==1?(($2-a1_min)/(a1_max-a1_min)):($1==2?(($2-a2_min)/(a2_max-a2_min)):($1==3?(($2-a3_min)/(a3_max-a3_min)):($1==4?(($2-a4_min)/(a4_max-a4_min)):($1==5?(($2-a5_min)/(a5_max-a5_min)):$1))))) w l
1 6
2 1.5
3 85
4 2010
5 0.5
1 6
```

Comment: Check this one [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649826/how-to-highlight-regions-of-plot-with-gnuplot/30684027#30684027], its a lot easier to adjust the number of stars etc.

Answer (score 3):

here's a hack attempt..

```
set nokey
set polar
set grid polar
set angles degrees
set size square
set style data lines
a1=0
a2=30
a3=100
a4=200
a5=300
set arrow nohead from 0,0 to first 10*cos(a1) , 10*sin(a1)
set arrow nohead from 0,0 to first 10*cos(a2) , 10*sin(a2)
set arrow nohead from 0,0 to first 10*cos(a3) , 10*sin(a3)
set arrow nohead from 0,0 to first 10*cos(a4) , 10*sin(a4)
set arrow nohead from 0,0 to first 10*cos(a5) , 10*sin(a5)
set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [-10:10]
plot '-' using ($1==1?a1:($1==2?a2:($1==3?a3:($1==4?a4:($1==5?a5:$1))))):2 lt 2
1 4
2 8
3 6
4 9
5 5
1 4
```

Comment: Thank you @george for your answer! Very much appreciated. The logical function in the using field for the plot command has greatly helped me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a suggestion for a "spider-plot" taken from my collection.
Since it uses data from a datablock instead from a file (because it's easier to address certain lines, e.g. via `$Data[1]`), therefore, it **requires gnuplot >=5.2.0**.
The actual data is in `$Data` and some settings for ranges and custom offset adjustments are in `$Settings`. 
The number of axes is automatically adjusted if you add some more rows in `$Data` and `$Settings`. Data needs to be separated by whitespace, because the gnuplot function `word(string,number)` is used to extract some values.

I hope it is more or less self-explaining. Comments, report of bugs or improvements are welcome.

**Code:**

```
### spider plot/chart with gnuplot 
# also known as: radar chart, web chart, star chart, cobweb chart, 
#                radar plot,  web plot,  star plot,  cobweb plot,  etc. ...
reset session
set size square
unset tics
set angles degree
set key top left

# Data
$Data <<EOD
SpiderData     "Product A"  "Product B"  "Product C"  "Product D"
Colors                red        green         blue       violet
"attribute 1"           2           10            7          3.5
"attribute 2"           1          0.5            3            4
"attribute 3"          37           58           49           72
"attribute 4"        1985         1992         2006         2010
"attribute 5"         0.1          0.5          0.3          0.8
EOD
HeaderLines = 2

# Settings for scale and offset adjustments
# axis min max tics axisLabelXoff axisLabelYoff ticLabelXoff ticLabelYoff
$Settings <<EOD
1     0    12  6  0.00 -0.02 -0.05  0.00
2     0     6  6  0.00  0.05  0.00  0.05
3    30    90  6  0.00  0.00  0.05  0.03
4  1980  2016  6  0.00  0.00  0.09 -0.02
5     0   1.2  6  0.00  0.05  0.00 -0.05
EOD

# General settings
DataColCount = words($Data[1])-1
AxesCount = |$Data|-HeaderLines
AngleOffset = 90
Max = 1
d=0.1*Max
Direction = -1   # counterclockwise=1, clockwise = -1

# Tic settings
TicCount = 6
TicValue(axis,i) = real(i)*(word($Settings[axis],3)-word($Settings[axis],2)) \
          / word($Settings[axis],4)+word($Settings[axis],2)
TicLabelPosX(axis,i) = PosX(axis,i/TicCount) + word($Settings[axis],7)
TicLabelPosY(axis,i) = PosY(axis,i/TicCount) + word($Settings[axis],8)
TicLen = 0.03
TicdX(axis,i) = 0.5*TicLen*cos(alpha(axis)-90)
TicdY(axis,i) = 0.5*TicLen*sin(alpha(axis)-90)

# Functions
alpha(axis) = (axis-1)*Direction*360.0/AxesCount+AngleOffset
PosX(axis,R) = R*cos(alpha(axis))
PosY(axis,R) = R*sin(alpha(axis))
Scale(axis,value) = real(value-word($Settings[axis],2))/(word($Settings[axis],3)-word($Settings[axis],2))

# Spider settings
set style arrow 1 dt 1 lw 1.0 lc -1 head     # style for axes
set style arrow 2 dt 2 lw 0.5 lc -1 nohead   # style for weblines
set style arrow 3 dt 1 lw 1 lc -1 nohead     # style for axis tics
set samples AxesCount
set isosamples TicCount
set urange[1:AxesCount]
set vrange[1:TicCount]
do for [i=1:DataColCount] {                  # set linetypes/colors
    set linetype i lc rgb word($Data[2],i+1)
}
set style fill transparent solid 0.2

set xrange[-Max-4*d:Max+4*d]
set yrange[-Max-4*d:Max+4*d]
plot \
    '+' u (0):(0):(PosX($0,Max+d)):(PosY($0,Max+d)) w vec as 1 not, \
    $Data u (PosX($0+1,Max+2*d)+word($Settings[$0+1],5)): \
        (PosY($0+1,Max+2*d)+word($Settings[$0+1],6)):1 every ::HeaderLines w labels center enhanced not, \
    '++' u (PosX($1,$2/TicCount)):(PosY($1,$2/TicCount)): \
        (PosX($1+1,$2/TicCount)-PosX($1,$2/TicCount)):  \
        (PosY($1+1,$2/TicCount)-PosY($1,$2/TicCount)) w vec as 2 not, \
    '++' u (PosX($1,$2/TicCount)-TicdX($1,$2/TicCount)): \
        (PosY($1,$2/TicCount)-TicdY($1,$2/TicCount)): \
        (2*TicdX($1,$2/TicCount)):(2*TicdY($1,$2/TicCount)) \
        w vec as 3 not, \
    for [i=1:DataColCount] $Data u (PosX($0+1,Scale($0+1,column(i+1)))): \
        (PosY($0+1,Scale($0+1,column(i+1)))) every ::HeaderLines w filledcurves lt i title word($Data[1],i+1), \
    '++' u (TicLabelPosX($1,$2)):(TicLabelPosY($1,$2)): \
        (sprintf("%g",TicValue($1,$2))) w labels font ",8" not
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: it has to be mentioned, gnuplot 5.4 offers spider plots in a shorter way: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/spiderplot.html

Answer (score 0):

The following repo shows a spider chart with homogeneous scales. https://github.com/orey/gnuplot-radarchart

For your particular case, I would:
-Create functions that would normalize all data to fit in the diagram scale,
-Hide tge standard scale,
-Use arrows for the axis,
-Add points with labels for your particular scales and place them with your data functions.

I think inspiration can be found in the repo.