# How to highlight regions of plot with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, highlight, radar-chart

I'd appreciate if somebody can help with this question. 
I am working with a radar (or spiderweb) plot with gnuplot 5.0.0:

[image]

The scale and range in all axes is the same. The numbers at and beyond 1 have a special meaning and I would like to highlight that.

I am thinking of three things that would increase visibility:

1. Simply make the tick mark at 1 (labelled "Limit") boldfaced. How could I highlight just a specific tick and label?
2. I could also highlight the circular dashed line at level 1
3. On the plot itself I'd like to have the background colored differently for radius > 1.

How can I achieve either of the three options above?  All three would be ideal of course, but just a a minimum differentiation from the rest of that value would help.

### This is what generated the plot in the link:

```
set term x11
set title "My title "
set polar
set angles degrees
npoints = 6

a1 = 360/npoints*1
a2 = 360/npoints*2
a3 = 360/npoints*3
a4 = 360/npoints*4
a5 = 360/npoints*5
a6 = 360/npoints*6

set grid polar 360
set size square
set style data lines

unset border

set grid ls 0
set linetype 1 lc rgb 'red' lw 2 pt 7 ps 2

M=2.2
set arrow from 0,0 to first M*cos(a1), M*sin(a1)
set arrow from 0,0 to first M*cos(a2), M*sin(a2)
set arrow from 0,0 to first M*cos(a3), M*sin(a3)
set arrow from 0,0 to first M*cos(a4), M*sin(a4)
set arrow from 0,0 to first M*cos(a5), M*sin(a5)
set arrow from 0,0 to first M*cos(a6), M*sin(a6)

a1_min = 0
a1_max = 1
a2_min = 0
a2_max = 1
a3_min = 0
a3_max = 1
a4_min = 0
a4_max = 1
a5_min = 0
a5_max = 1
a6_min = 0
a6_max = 1

set label "M1" at M*cos(a1),M*sin(a1) center offset char 1,1
set label "M2" at M*cos(a2),M*sin(a2) center offset char 1,1
set label "M3" at M*cos(a3),M*sin(a3) center offset char 1,1
set label "M4" at M*cos(a4),M*sin(a4) center offset char 1,1
set label "M5" at M*cos(a5),M*sin(a5) center offset char 1,1
set label "M6" at M*cos(a6),M*sin(a6) center offset char 1,1


set xrange [0:1]
set yrange [0:1]

set xtics axis 0,0.5,M
unset ytics

set rrange [0:M]

set rtics (""0,""0.25,""0.5,""0.75,"Limit"1,""1.25,""1.50,""1.75,""2)
set rtics scale 0 format ''

set style fill transparent solid 0.5
set style function filledcurves y1=0.5
set grid noxtics nomxtics noytics nomytics front


plot  '-' u ($1==1?a1:($1==2?a2:($1==3?a3:($1==4?a4:($1==5?a5:($1==6?a6:$1)))))):($1==1?(($2-a1_min)/(a1_max-a1_min)):($1==2?(($2-a2_min)/(a2_max-a2_min)):($1==3?(($2-a3_min)/(a3_max-a3_min)):($1==4?(($2-a4_min)/(a4_max-a4_min)):($1==5?(($2-a5_min)/(a5_max-a5_min)):($1==6?(($2-a6_min)/(a6_max-a6_min)):$1)))))) w filledcurve lt 1 title "AAA",\
 '-' u ($1==1?a1:($1==2?a2:($1==3?a3:($1==4?a4:($1==5?a5:($1==6?a6:$1)))))):($1==1?(($2-a1_min)/(a1_max-a1_min)):($1==2?(($2-a2_min)/(a2_max-a2_min)):($1==3?(($2-a3_min)/(a3_max-a3_min)):($1==4?(($2-a4_min)/(a4_max-a4_min)):($1==5?(($2-a5_min)/(a5_max-a5_min)):($1==6?(($2-a6_min)/(a6_max-a6_min)):$1)))))) w filledcurve lt 2 title "BBB"

1 2.1
2 1
3 0.1
4 0.5
5 0.5
6 0.1
1 2.1
EOF
1 2.2
2 0.9
3 0.9
4 0.2
5 0.3
6 0.1
1 2.2
EOF
set output
```

Comment: At the moment Google Drive requires people to have a permission to see your graph.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I just changed that to let anybody with the link to be able to view it.

Comment: I uploaded the picture for you

Comment: You can use enhanced text to have a bold ticslabel: _set xtics add ("{/:Bold Limit}" 1)_

Comment: For highlighting the grid line at one, you could draw a circle ("set object circle") or plot it: _plot ...., [phi=0:2*pi] "+" us (sin(phi)):(cos(phi)) w l dt 2 lw 2_

Comment: Thank you Miguel and Karl. I could not make the bold tic label work, but the "set object circle" did:      set object 2 circle at 0,0 size first 1 fc rgb "#CCFFCC" behind fs solid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've taken the liberty to streamline your script a bit, you can now easily adjust the number of arms in the web. Also added a coloured background for 1  >r > M.

Btw., there is no need to enter the first datapoint again at the end to close the contour.
Update: That is, there shouldn't be. However the line between the last and first point is missing then, even with giving the "closed" option to "with filledcurve". I wonder if this is a bug.

```
set term wxt
set title "My title "
set polar
set angles degrees

set grid polar 360
set size square
set style data lines
set key top left

unset border

set grid ls 0
set linetype 1 lc rgb 'red' lw 2 pt 7 ps 2

M=2.2
npoints = 7

minima = "0 0 0 0 0 0 0" # adjust and add more as necessary
maxima = "1 1 1 1 1 1 1"

a(n) = 360./npoints*n
amin(n) = 0.0 + word(minima,int(n))
amax(n) = 0.0 + word(maxima,int(n))

do for [i=1:npoints] {
    set arrow i from 0,0 to first M*cos(a(i)), M*sin(a(i))
    set label i sprintf("M%.f",i) at M*cos(a(i)),M*sin(a(i)) \
        center offset char 1,1
}

set object 1 circle at 0,0 size M fillc rgb "yellow" behind
set object 2 circle at 0,0 size 1 fillc rgb "white" behind

set xrange [0:1]
set yrange [0:1]

set xtics axis 0,0.5,M
unset ytics

set rrange [0:M]

set rtics (""0,""0.25,""0.5,""0.75,"{/:Bold Limit}"1,""1.25,""1.50,""1.75,""2)
set rtics scale 0 format ''

set style fill transparent solid 0.5
set style function filledcurves y1=0.5
set grid noxtics nomxtics noytics nomytics front

plot '-' us (a($1)):(($2-amin($1))/(amax($1)-amin($1))) \
        w filledcurve closed lt 1 title "AAA",\
     '-' us (a($1)):(($2-amin($1))/(amax($1)-amin($1))) \
         w filledcurve closed lt 2 title "BBB"

1 2.1
2 1
3 0.1
4 0.5
5 0.5
6 0.1
7 0.5
EOF
1 2.2
2 0.9
3 0.9
4 0.2
5 0.3
6 0.1
7 1.8
EOF
```

Comment: Karl, this goes well beyond what I asked. I'll test your changes and report back.  I've learnt a couple of things since I posted my question. I very much appreciate your having taken the time to do this.

Comment: Karl, I tried your tweaked script and it works. I adopted it. Thanks again. Your version looks more elegant with the use of vectors and for loops. I had also used vectors and for loops , but I did this in the code that generated my script.

Comment: I just added a coloured background like you asked for in you original question. Note the "behind" option to place a filled object behind the grid and axes.

Comment: Thanks again, Karl.  I'd consider your latest input as the best answer to my question.  How do I close this thread and mark it as answered?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, you can only upvote my answer, afaik.