# How to make a spider plot in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, spider-chart

Let's say my data is in the form:

```
#atom a b c
43 1.2 1.3 1.4
44 1.2 1.4 1.8
45 1.3 1.8 1.9
46 2.0 2.3 2.4
47 1.5 1.6 1.8
```

And I want a plot like this one http://www.r-graph-gallery.com/143-spider-chart-with-saveral-individuals/ (the one in the middle).

how can I do that?

ps. The title in here ([How to Create a Spider Plot in Gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709820/how-to-create-a-spider-plot-in-gnuplot)) is misleading...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no built-in functionality which would directly give you the linked output. Nevertheless, one could improvise with the tools that Gnuplot does provide. The strategy would be to:

1. analyze the file and determine the number of vertices
2. generate the "polygonial" grid in parametric mode
3. plot the data using the `filledcurves` plotting style (with transparency)

For example (the data is represented as a datablock instead of directly passing a file):

```
reset session
set terminal pngcairo enhanced font "Times,16"
set output 'plot.png'

$DATA << EOD
#atom a b c
43 1.2 1.3 1.4
44 1.2 1.4 1.8
45 1.3 1.8 1.9
46 2.0 2.3 2.4
47 1.5 1.6 1.8
EOD

stats $DATA nooutput

N = STATS_columns
M = STATS_records

set angles degrees
set size ratio -1
set style fill transparent solid 0.25

unset key
unset border
unset xtics
unset ytics

colors = "dark-red royalblue forest-green"

set style line 42 lt 1 lc rgb '#333333' dt 3 lw 0.8

deltaR = 0.5
maxR = 3 + deltaR/4
numOfStepsInR = floor((1.*maxR) / deltaR)

#helper functions
alpha(i) = 90. - i*360./M
posX(i, r) = cos(alpha(i))*r
posY(i, r) = sin(alpha(i))*r
lcolor(i) = word(colors, i%words(colors) + 1)

do for [i=0:M-1] {
  stats $DATA every ::i::i using (labelValue=$1) nooutput
  set label sprintf("%d", labelValue) at posX(i,maxR),posY(i,maxR) center offset char posX(i,1),char posY(i,1)
}

do for [j=1:numOfStepsInR] {
  set label sprintf("%.1f", j*deltaR) at 0,j*deltaR left offset char 0.5,0 tc rgb '#333333'
}

set parametric
set tr [0:1]

set xr [-1.1*maxR:1.1*maxR]
set yr [-1.1*maxR:1.1*maxR]

plot \
  for [i=0:M-1] \
    (cos(alpha(i))*(deltaR*(1-t)+t*maxR)),(sin(alpha(i))*(deltaR*(1-t)+t*maxR)) w l ls 42, \
  for [i=0:M-1] for [j=1:numOfStepsInR] \
    (j*deltaR*cos(alpha(i))*t + (1-t)*j*deltaR*cos(alpha(i+1))),(j*deltaR*sin(alpha(i))*t + (1-t)*j*deltaR*sin(alpha(i+1))) w l ls 42, \
  for [i=2:N] $DATA u (posX($0, column(i))):(posY($0, column(i))) w filledcurves closed fc rgb lcolor(i-2) fs border lc rgb lcolor(i-2) lw 2, \
  for [i=2:N] $DATA u (posX($0, column(i))):(posY($0, column(i))) w p ps 1.2 pt 7 lc rgb lcolor(i-2)
```

This produces:
[image]

Comment: the `array` line says it is an invalid command. Got gnuplot Version 5.0 patchlevel 6

Comment: @murpholinox array support was added in 5.1, I have modified the answer so that it uses the `word` function workaround...

Comment: Thanks a lot. would you care to explain it a little bit. :P

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. In fact, in my case the first column represented a string value (basically the name of the "vertexes" of the spider plot). Therefore, the trick of using the setlabel with sprintf did not work, as it required a stat command that failed.

I solved by removing the setlabel loop and adding this plot line before all other plots
```plot datafile u (posX($0,maxR*1.1)):(posY($0,maxR*1.1)):1 w labels,\
...```