# A better way of plotting a 'Spider Chart' from Haskell data?

Tags: haskell, plot, data-analysis

I want to try Haskell out for a small practice data analysis project.
I have a lot of data each processed and represented in Haskell Data type I named as `Eap`

I have a list of `Eap` where each `Eap` looks like this

```
Eap
  { _name = Just "someName"
    _size = Just 50.0
    _dmsTypes = Just
      ( Dms
           { _i = Just 50.0
           , _j = Just 5.0
           , _k = Just 90.0
           , _l = Nothing
           , _m = Just 100.0
           , _n = Just 10.0
           }
      )
    }
```

What I want to do is understand the data by plotting a 'Spider Chart' which look like this [image: here]

I want to plot it such that each of six vertex represents `_i`, `_j`, `_k` .. `_n` from `Dms`. Since there's a list of `Eap`s each `Dms` would have different colors.

Right now the best way I found is as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49847005/9235239).

It involves using gnuplot. And gnuplot has wrapper as a Haskell package over at [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gnuplot)

And while it's possible to implement that in Haskell with gnuplot, the code becomes quite error prone and really unreadable. Debugging becomes a mess.

So I wanted to ask, is there a better way of plotting a 'Spider chart' of Haskell data which is relatively easy and maintainable?

Comment: I would probably use [`diagrams`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams) for this if I wanted to avoid gnuplot. But I think this question is unfortunately off-topic for SO because it asks for a tool recommendation, which usually has no objective answer.

Comment: Write it yourself an option?

Comment: @JonPurdy I don't necessarily want to be gnuplot free, I thought maybe there's a way of doing most of the work in Haskell and letting gnuplot just 'render' the final product instead the other way around. Although diagrams does seem really promising.